# Issue with ScrollableGraphicView Swift Library in Objective C project

Tags: ios, swift, datasource

Hello everyone for my chart in my app I'm using the MIT **ScrollableGraphView** library written entirely in **Swift** Language.

This is the link of Ghitub https://github.com/philackm/ScrollableGraphView

To use this library in my **ObjectiveC** project, I imported this into my view controller file:

```
#import "TargetName-Swift.h"
```

Then to work with the library we need to include `<ScrollableGraphViewDataSource>`

At this point the documentation says to allocate the class in this way

```
ScrollableGraphView * graphView = [[ScrollableGraphView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame dataSource: self];
```

This is my complete ViewController.m

```
#import "TargetName-Swift.h"

@interface Dashboard () <ScrollableGraphViewDataSource>
@end

@implementation Dashboard

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ScrollableGraphView *graphView = [[ScrollableGraphView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame dataSource: self];
    [self.view addSubview: graphView];
}
```

My problem is that xCode returns this error to me

**No visible @interface for 'ScrollableGraphView' declares the selector 'initWithFrame: dataSource:'**

I think I have followed all the necessary instructions to use this library but I do not understand why I can not find the class allocation with datasource

In the ScrollableGraphView.swift file, the class allocation also includes the datasource

```
public init (frame: CGRect, dataSource: ScrollableGraphViewDataSource) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        super.init (frame: frame)
    }
```

so I do not understand why I can not allocate the class in objective C ..

Where am I doing wrong? has anyone ever used this library? do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: @Larme Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name... I know for integration swift library in objective c project I need to insert #import"projectName-Swift.h"

Comment: Have you tried adding `@objc` to the Swift source?

Comment: @OOPer add your answer... this is correct for me

Comment: Please write an answer by yourself. I usually do not write something as an answer when I cannot confirm it really works. And I have no time to confirm with actual ScrollableGraphView now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in my case the class allocation in the swift source file did not have the extension **@objc**

As soon as I added this before initialization, everything worked perfectly for me ...

This was the change:

Old source

```
public init(frame: CGRect, dataSource: ScrollableGraphViewDataSource) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
```

Source with the addition of @ objc

```
@objc public init(frame: CGRect, dataSource: ScrollableGraphViewDataSource) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
```

Now everything works ... I also thank **OOPer** for his suggestion that in this case it was correct!